# How to setup Django on XMPP on Windows XP

Tags: windows, django, xampp

Greetings!

I'd like to investigate Django but I'm running Windows XP.  I've installed XMPP and I currently have Python 2.6 installed (is it true that 2.5 is the only version that will work with XMPP?).  What else do I need to get up and running? Any tips, recommended IDEs, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sam says, for development, use the dev server. Using a "real" server is actually more of a pain because you have to make sure it reloads your project when you make edits. You can also beat it into hosting all your media while in a development environment, if that's what you need (as most people do).

As far as IDE's go, Python is a hard language to provide auto-complete features for due to its dynamic typing. That said PyDev (an Eclipse plug-in) can make life easier for you but it's really down to personal choice.

Half of Django is writing HTML templates, so make sure you've got a good HTML editor to hand as well. Eclipse (IMO, naturally) is far too clunky for this (even with Aptana, et al plugins)

Comment: So if I use the dev server, does that negate the need for XMPP?

Answer (score 2):

If your just going to play around with django i'd recommend using the built-in [development server](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-optional-port-number-or-ipaddr-port). for easyness have a server launcher shortcut in your project folder.
runserver.cmd:

```
@echo off
python manage.py runserver
```

As for the IDE, i'd recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it to work under Apache, try [this from the Django docs.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/?from=olddocs) Otherwise, use the development server. If you want a simple way to get started, try [Instant Django](http://www.instantdjango.com/), although this only has Python 2.5.2.

Finally, concerning IDEs, a good text editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) or [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) will suffice. If you want a Python IDE, there is a good list at [the Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments), and [SPE](http://pythonide.blogspot.com/) has always worked fine for me.

(Oh, and one tip: have two cmd windows open - one for the server and one for testing, syncdb-ing, etc.)